# Import key statistics without a header row

Tags: google-sheets

I'm interested in pulling a specific # from Yahoo Finance.

[I'm looking at American Airlines AAL](https://finance.yahoo.com/q/ks?s=aal&ql=1)

I have found the table:

```
=importhtml("https://finance.yahoo.com/q/ks?s=aal&ql=1","table",11)
```

But I am having trouble trying to query the Price/Sales (ttm): information.

This is what I have and when I tried to query it:

```
=query(importhtml("https://finance.yahoo.com/q/ks?s=aal&ql=1","table",11), "where Col1 = 'Price/Sales (ttm):'")
```

[image]

How do I not include the Market Cap?

Answer (score 5):

If you don't want the header row with "Market Cap", tell the `query` command that the table has no header. The optional third parameter of `query` is the number of header rows. (When it's not provided, the spreadsheet will make a guess based on the appearance of the data, which is not always a correct guess).

`=query(importhtml(...), "where Col1 = 'Price/Sales (ttm):'", 0)`